# Flask: Restarting with reloader can't find file

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I'm trying to learn flask. I've created a virtual environment (venv) in my project directory (C:\users\ian\git\flasktutorial). FLASK_APP is set to flasktutorial, FLASK_DEBUG=1, and I do have a flasktutorial.py in the directory.

When I type "flask run" I get the following:

```
* Serving Flask app "flasktutorial"
* Forcing debug mode on
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with windowsapi reloader
c:\users\ian\git\flasktutorial\venv\scripts\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\users\Ian\Git\flasktutorial\venv\Scripts\flask': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Checking that folder, it does seem to have a flask.exe in it. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: An out of scope advice: switch your OS to Linux. It will pay back the time you'll spend on it. Now you are going to be solving the side-effects of using Windows as your Python development environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run flask as a module, then the reloader will work on Windows:

```
python -m flask run
```

Explanation:

When starting the app in Windows with `flask.exe` then the reloader constructs wrong args for the new subprocess. Source code [here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/a2a5f5a4c04c5b1fb33709bc2cdc297cd8fb46a3/werkzeug/_reloader.py#L96).

It tries to run the python interpreter with `flask.exe` as script name, but *without the extension*, this is the the reason for the file not found error. 
If you make a dupe and copy Scripts/flask.exe to Scripts/flask then it will work. ;)

Otherwise, when running flask as a module then the sys.argv contains proper paths for the reloader to run the subprocess.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much! Do you know why this works?

Comment: I added the reason I am aware of.